# How to build this regex to find a string in a string?

Tags: regex

I would like to build a regex to find a string in a string. The regex will be as follows and in order:

- a dash
- a white space
- alphanumeric and underscore (can be mixed as dsa_ds456 or _45_74d_ds)
- a white space

Examples valid:

blablabla - userid1 the rest of my text *extracted string: - userid1*

blablabla - us58_d1 the rest of my text *extracted string:- us58_d1*

blablabla - _45dssd the rest of my text *extracted string:- _45dssd*

Examples invalid:

blablabla - the rest of my text

How would you write it down ?

Comment: `(- [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ )`?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I couldnt come up with one single solution as I have no idea on how to build a regex. If you dont want to help, fine ! Others may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need lookahead support here, use this regex:

```
"-\\s(?=.*?[_\\d])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(\\w+)"
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eT4jE0